# Python: pandas confusion matrix issue

Tags: python, pandas

I do not know how to write a better title for this problem. It works like this: I have a CSV file populated with some data. CSV file looks like this:

```
14 tests runed: 6 passed and 8 failed with accuracy: 42.00%
Picture name    ; Detected as       ; Status
categ1_0.jpg    ; categ8=0.875931   ; Failed
categ1_1.jpg    ; categ8=0.553985   ; Failed
categ2_0.jpg    ; categ2=0.994332   ; Passed
categ2_1.jpg    ; categ2=0.994736   ; Passed
categ3_0.jpg    ; categ3=0.97933    ; Passed
categ3_1.jpg    ; categ3=0.825793   ; Failed
categ4_0.jpg    ; categ4=0.63532    ; Failed
categ4_1.jpg    ; categ4=0.520756   ; Failed
categ5_0.jpg    ; categ5=0.999963   ; Failed
categ5_1.jpg    ; categ5=0.999827   ; Failed
categ6_0.jpg    ; categ6=0.99825    ; Passed
categ6_1.jpg    ; categ6=0.475022   ; Failed
categ7_0.jpg    ; categ7=0.9987     ; Passed
categ7_1.jpg    ; categ7=0.982103   ; Passed
```

Out of this, I extract a confusion matrix using this python code (code works):

```
import csv
import argparse
import pandas as pd

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Creating confusion matrix.')
parser.add_argument('-i', '--input', help='Input path/to/file.csv', required=True)
parser.add_argument('-ca', '--categ-path', nargs='+', help='Name of categories (do not separe by other characters)', required=True)
parser.add_argument('-oh', '--output-html', help='Output path/to/confusion_matrix.html', required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()

data = csv.reader(open(args.input, 'r'), delimiter=";", quotechar='|')
next(data)
next(data)

true_data = []
pred_data = []

for row in data:
    if len(row) >= 2:
        true_data.append(row[0])
        pred_data.append(row[1])

true_data = [s.strip().split('_')[0] for s in true_data]
pred_data = [s.strip().split('=')[0] for s in pred_data]

y_true = pd.Series(true_data, name="Actual")
y_pred = pd.Series(pred_data, name="Predicted")

df_confusion = pd.crosstab(y_true, y_pred)
df_confusion.to_html(args.output_html)
```

However, if i change the following line:

```
y_true = pd.Series(args.categ_path, name="Actual")
```

It does no longer work. When i say this, i'm referring to the fact that it does not show the whole Predicted categories. For example, if the Predicted categories in working version are `categ8 | categ2 | categ3 | etc` (all the ones taken from `Detected as` column), in the non-working version i will have only 3 of those categories (not all of them).

What i want to accomplish is to give the true category names in command line instead of taking them from the CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. In case someone encounters the same problem: the true (actual) results must have the same number of entries as the predicted results.

One simply can't expect 1 picture to be interpreted by a model in 20 different ways, with the same confidence :)